# XCode: How to handle Space character in string?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to ask if I want to create a NSString, such as

```
for ( int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    NSString *picURLstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Testing/files/Demo Presentation/Slide%d.JPG", i] ;
...
}
```

This is part of my code, so that I can later get the URL of 10 images. Then I use this URL to download the images from my server, but it seems dont work. But while I change the file in my server from "Demo Presentation" to "DemoPresentation", also the Xcode statement to:

```
    for ( int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    NSString *picURLstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Testing/files/DemoPresentation/Slide%d.JPG", i] ;
...
}
```

It works! It can download the images I need from my server. So may I ask how to implement a space inside a string? I tried to use %20, thus "Demo%20Presentation" in the string, but it still not working, please help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what goes wrong? What do you mean by "no string is got after my testing"?

Comment: How do you use this string afterwards?

Comment: NSString *encodedString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; try like this
For your case.....    
for ( int i=1; i<=10; i++) {

NSString *picURLString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Testing/files/Demo Presentation/Slide%d.JPG", i] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}

Comment: Sorry about my bad english, I edited the question to elaborate the error.

Comment: @ChowCena are you tried my comment

Comment: @Spynet trying, thanks for your help first

Comment: Thanks @Spynet , it works perfectly now with no error, thanks for the help! Really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for ( int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    NSString *picURLstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Testing/files/Demo Presentation/Slide%d.JPG", i] ;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[picURLstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //use url ...
}
```